# No module named 'bitmex_websocket'

Tags: python-3.x, api, websocket

I am very new to coding so bear with me. I am trying to connect to the websocket API from bitmex. I am following this exactly but with my API keys and on mainnet. I have tried as they show it as well but same error on Line 1!!! https://github.com/BitMEX/api-connectors/tree/master/official-ws/python

I tried reinstalling python and my IDE. Other modules work such as numpy. There are several github repos showing they are connecting to the websocket using what it shows in the github I linked above with no apparent issue but I cannot run them as I get the same error. I assume this is going to be something ridiculously easy so thank you in advance.

```
from bitmex_websocket import BitMEXWebsocket
ws=BitMEXWebsocket(endpoint="https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1",symbol="XBTUSD",api_key="MY API KEY", api_secret="MY API KEY")
```

This is the console from pycharm.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ben/PycharmProjects/BitmexTrends/main.py", line 1, in 
    import bitmex_websocket
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitmex_websocket'

Edit: Yes I have pip installed bitmex-ws sorry.

This is what gets installed on pip install bitmex-ws if it helps: [sitepackages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhKvD.png)

Comment: `pip install bitmex-websocket` use this command to install the module.

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi Sorry should have said I have done that. Edited it now in the post. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was me not knowing how PyCharm works! Went to settings -> interpreter -> + -> bitmex-ws -> install.

But I tried this in vs code and same error as well. Do I also need to add the packages there as well? Little confused as I did not think this was necessary to do to work in these IDEs.